# Scala: Implicitly render objects into complex XML?

Tags: xml, scala, implicit-conversion

For example, how can I (or why can't I) automatically convert all `URL` objects to a relevant hyper-link using an `implicit` method such as this:

```
implicit def urlToXML(url: URL): xml.Node =
  <a href={ url.toString }>{ url.getHost + url.getPath }</a>
```

Then I might (implicitly) use it like so:

```
val myURL = new URL("https://example.com")
<p>Hey, come check out my cool new website at { myURL }.</p>
```

Scala (2.11.5) seems to ignore the `implicit` method and convert the `URL` object straight to a string.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when using braces to escape an XML literal, a `String` is expected.  If an object is found, then `toString` is called.  You can see that here:

```
<p>{ new {} }</p> //returns <p>$anon$1@17aaa54f</p>
```

You're probably used to just inserting other XML nodes in the braces, because `toString` works well on `Node`, allowing you to do things like:

```
<p>{ <div/> }</p> //returns <p><div/></p>
```

But this only really works because `<div/>.toString == "<div/>"`.  So in your case, the compiler has no way of knowing that you want to convert the `myUrl` to a `Node`, and *then* call `toString` -- it thinks it can just call `toString` on the `URL`.

There's a couple of ways around this.  You can use type ascription to trigger the implicit conversion:

```
<p>Hey, come check out my cool new website at { myURL:Node }.</p>
```

You can explicitly call the method (in this version, you don't need the implicit conversion):

```
<p>Hey, come check out my cool new website at { urlToXml(myURL) }.</p>
```

Or make a wrapper method that expects a `Node`:

```
def insertUrl(urlNode: Node) = <p>Hey, come check out my cool new website at { urlNode }.</p>
insertUrl(myUrl) //The implicit comes in to play here
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversions have to be triggered by either an expected type or a member selection. In this case, the expected type for the embedded Scala expression is `Any`.

This is how it compiles:

```
scala> <tag>{ 42 }{ new java.net.URI("http://acme.com") }</tag>
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <console>
package $line3 {
  object $read extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): $line3.$read.type = {
      $read.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
      def <init>(): type = {
        $iw.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      object $iw extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>(): type = {
          $iw.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        private[this] val res0: scala.xml.Elem = {
          {
            new scala.xml.Elem(null, "tag", scala.xml.Null, scala.this.xml.TopScope, false, ({
              val $buf: scala.xml.NodeBuffer = new scala.xml.NodeBuffer();
              $buf.&+(42);
              $buf.&+(new java.net.URI("http://acme.com"));
              $buf
            }: _*))
          }
        };
        <stable> <accessor> def res0: scala.xml.Elem = $iw.this.res0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The doc is [here for `NodeBuffer.&+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-xml/index.html#scala.xml.NodeBuffer@&+(o:Any):scala.xml.NodeBuffer).

So alternatively,

```
scala> implicit class `uri anchor`(val u: java.net.URI) { def a = <a href={ u.toString }>{ u.getHost }</a> }
defined class uri$u0020anchor

scala> <tag>{ new java.net.URI("http://acme.com").a }</tag>
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <tag><a href="http://acme.com">acme.com</a></tag>

scala>
```

The other alternative is to provide a custom xml library that takes a useful type in that location, such as `Embeddable`, for which you could provide the type classes you want.

The other alternative is to anticipate the Scala future and use an interpolator.