# Customize scala xml interpolation

Tags: scala, scala-xml

When I insert arbitrary expressions inside xml literals it seems that result of `.toString()` is inserted

```
object Foo {
  override def toString: String = "foo"
}
println(<div>{Foo}</div>) // prints "<div>foo</div>"
```

Can I customize that process in a way other than overriding toString? Add method toXml or something? Note, I'd like to avoid explicit `<div>{Foo.toXml}</div>`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way without explicitly calling the conversion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052619/scala-implicitly-render-objects-into-complex-xml.